# Flask app gives a 500 (internal server error) page (without any error traceback) when trying to upload an image. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, flask

I'm currently trying to build a flask app which will accept an uploaded image, allow the user to apply filters to that image, and then let the user view their library of uploaded and filtered images. I have a method called `upload()`, and a template `upload.html`, which are printed in the code snippets below - I have tried three different versions of `upload()` based on tutorials for uploading images in flask, and each of them have the same result. The upload template with the form loads normally, I upload an image, and then I get an internal server error. I go back to the terminal in my IDE (I'm using the CS50 IDE) to check where the error came from, and there is no traceback whatsoever.

What's weird is that I've based the second and third attempts at implementing this on tutorials I've seen, in which the exact same implementation worked just fine.

Here is the HTML template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Upload
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <input type="file" name="image">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

The first version of `upload()`:

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("upload.html")
    if request.files:
        #The POST request came through with an image file.
        image = request.files['image']

        if image.filename == "":
            print("No filename")
            return redirect("/upload")
        if image and allowed_image(image.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(image.filename)
            image.save(os.path.join(app.config['IMAGE_UPLOADS'], filename))
            print("Image saved.")
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            print("That file extension is not allowed")
            return redirect("/upload")
    else:
        print("Not request.files")
        return render_template("upload.html")
```

The second, for which `photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)`, using the `flask_uploads` extension:

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
        filename = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
        print(filename)
        return redirect("/")
    return render_template('upload.html')
```

And the third:

```
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, "images/")
        print(target)

        if not os.path.isdir(target):
            os.mkdir(target)

        for file in request.files.getlist("image"):
            print(file)
            filename = file.filename
            destination = "/".join([target, filename])
            print(destination)
            file.save(destination)

        return render_template("index.html")
    else:
        return render_template("upload.html")
```

Here's an image of the upload screen
[image]

The Internal Server Error
[image]

Comment: Usually when you deal with this kind of things you take an extra look to the CLI. Do you get any messages in your terminal related to this issue?

Comment: That's an nginx error. Check your nginx log.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to upload files with `flask_uploads` [`pip install flask_uploads`]. With that, you don't have to write boilerplate code for uploading files.  NOTE - You might have to install specific version of werkzeug as `pip install werkzeug==0.16.0` in case you face problem as 'cannot import name 'secure_filename' from 'werkzeug''

Here is an example I found on GitHub.
https://gist.github.com/greyli/addff01c19ddca78cddf386800e57045

Comment: Instead of Flask-Uploads I recommend https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Reuploaded/ - this is  a fork and a drop in replacement, but better maintained and working PyPi releases - no special Werkzeug release necessary, as errors get fixed there.

Comment: I tried this, copying the code of your github example to see if it would work, and got the same 500 Internal Server error with the body text: "nginx/1.17.0 error". Another commenter said to check my nginx log, but since I'm using a cloud based IDE on this project, I can't find it. However, I think it must be a problem with the environment and not the rest of my code, because I set up a separate environment to test the example you linked.